# Someone else can easily use our SO flair

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, flair

i just got 200+ repu and was delighted to use my SO flair, but to my amusement, I found it is very easy to use someone else flair on other websites, just to show off, is this ok..?

Forgive me if I am asking wrong question, i just noticed and i thought to share it.Here is my the code for flair

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/1102092/sum2000">
<img src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1102092.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for sum2000 at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" title="profile for sum2000 at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers">
</a>
```

[image: profile for sum2000 at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

Now, if you browse top user and just copy their name and id , you get their flare, this is just a demo to bring people in light

```
<a href="https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom">
<img src="https://askubuntu.com/users/flair/14356.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for sum2000 at Ask Ubuntu, Q&amp;A for Ubuntu users and developers" title="profile for fossfreedom at Ask Ubuntu, Q&amp;A for Ubuntu users and developers">
</a>
```

**Notice the userid and name being replaced**

[image: profile for sum2000 at Ask Ubuntu, Q&A for Ubuntu users and developers]
    
Here it is, someone else flair.

Please, can someone look into this matter??

Comment: How would *you* "solve" this then? Just because someone might "steal" the flair doesn't mean they can, and really, who cares? If someone gets hired on a high rep only then they've got a job they probably can't do and the company needs to have higher vetting practises that looking at a number on a website.

Comment: I am the President of the United States, and I'm here to tell you that what you're describing is called "lying". There isn't a whole lot we can do about it, nor is it our job to somehow police it.

Answer (score 11):

That's not a bug, that's by design.

I can also change my displayname and avatar to match yours...or that of Jon Skeet...or Jeff Atwood...well, maybe better not Atwood (he has a [giant S](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105) which he uses to beat people up).

**Edit:** I can also link against your profile and tell people on my homepage "look, that's me". Yes, it is wrong, yes, it is bs...but what would you want to do about it?

Answer (score 6):

It's not like you're altering the link in such a way so as to bring yourself under the guise of this person, or say, displaying their attributes applied to your account in some magical, voodoo way (altering your account to reflect in such a way *could* be done, I guess, but then your other atts don't match up accordinlgy) - once you post the link to your flair, it's public anyway, so I could post it anywhere I liked.

Ask yourself, what could an exploiter benefit from this? Nothing, short of social engineering (which could happen anyway, flair or not) for some self-satisfying purposes, it's essentially just advertising an account, someone else's account, should they care to.

Your concerns are unwarranted.