# How to prove it's your flair

Tags: discussion, jobs, openid, flair

> "Stack Overflow has a popular job board which ties naturally into the
>   site as Stack Overflow reputation has become a big yardstick for
>   evaluating programmers."

ref: http://articles.businessinsider.com/2011-03-09/tech/30032632_1_q-a-verticals-investors

Say someone tried using someone else flair in their CV. Eg: they put a pic of Marc's flair in their CV:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/37VPr.png]

If you are not using Careers 2.0 how can one verify it's actually your flair? I was wondering if there is anything like what Microsoft do - an url with transcript ID and password I give to employers to verify my MCSD?

Comment: I would expect your potential employer to look at a bit more than just a set of numbers on a webpage.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116576/someone-else-can-easily-use-our-so-flair

Comment: @tombull89, hahaha that link was quite funny. I'm not looking for work, I was just curious. Recruiters would have no idea.. even photo-shopping the flair pic could fool them. Some mechanism would be helpful especially for Careers 2.0 (in non-us countries). I was thinking like a http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jeremythompson?pw=LoveLife

Comment: You put your name in your profile, I would think.  How can Jack Mehoff claim your flair when your accound says you're Wanda Bigone?

Comment: I've got my name as my userid, but joe blogs can pick any old profile without detail and tell recruiters its his

Comment: I'm going to say this isn't a dupe, since it's being asked specifically in the context of Careers. It's possible that the team could add additional verification between two sites it has control over that would be difficult or impractical in the general case. (I know tombull89 just said that link was related, but I just got here from `/review` and there are currently four votes to close as dupe of it.)